# Method similar to Scanner.hasNext for ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, netbeans, objectinputstream

I am reading from a .dat file with an unknown amount of objects within it. What I want to do is loop through the file by using the `.readObject()` method. Is there a way I can determine the amount of times to read the file similar to the way the `.hasNext()` method works for Scanner?

For example, I would normally use a while loop with `hasNext()` as a parameter.

```
while (scFile.hasNext()){ 
   x = scFile.nextInt();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the stream until EOFException is thrown. The method you are looking for does not exist.